# Difficulty provisioning iPad application for testing on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, deployment, provisioning-profile

I have a provisioning profile, registered my device, added the certificate, and created an app id for my application.  I set the provisioning profile in the Code Signing section on XCode and the App ID is set.  I had a problem where it said iPad-only applications should not use armv6 and the build failed so I followed some advice I read and set it to build active architecture only and now I don't receive any warnings, but the build still fails. The iPad is plugged in and I selected it from the drop down for running. Also I am using XCode 4 and I was trying to follow this tutorial http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-install-apps-on-iphone-devices-for-development/.

My professor created the provisioning profile and the app id, but I checked and everything looks fine except for one thing. When I look at the app ids on the developer page under "Apple Push Notification service" it says unavailable for the app I'm using, while some other app ids say "Configurable for Development". I'm not sure if that has to do with the problem but I thought it might be related.

I also tried doing a clean build because I saw that suggested somewhere, but it still failed so something must be wrong with how I set it up.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

edit: just thought of something else, under the organizer page if I click on applications my app isn't there and if I try to add it I get an error message saying "No Code Signature Found"

Also, if I look at the provisioning profiles the app id section is blank. Do I need to link the provisioning profile up to the app id some how?

Comment: can you add the build fail message?

Comment: Also, if you check the Devices tab of the Organizer window, you should see your device, and there should be a green light next to it.  If it is there, click on Provisioning Profiles and make sure that the development profile is listed there.  If it is there but showing a warning about the valid signing identity not found, the original creator of the development certificate would need to export a private key (.p12 file) that you can import into your keychain.

Comment: Hi Jesse thanks for replying, at the top it just says "Build ProjectName:Failed Today at..." and then underneath that "No issues".  Nothing is printed in the console and when I go to the warnings page nothing comes up.  Is there another place I should be looking for a build fail message?

Comment: Hi BP, the light is green and it doesn't have the valid signing identity warning any more. I had it previously this morning but then I added the correct certificate to the list of ok certificates and now the message is gone, but the build still fails.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, It might be helpful https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING_GUIDE-CODE_SIGNING_ENTITLEMENTS